# Populating arrays after their definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a `ul` containing `li`'s which contain names of different recipe ingredients for a recipe page. I'm trying to get those ingredients and store them into a JavaScript array within an object. I already know the title of the recipe so I put that right into the object property `title`, but I don't know how many ingredients there will be for each recipe. Here is what I have:

```
var recipeobj = {
        title: $('h3.title').val(),
        ingredients: [
                ingredient,
                optional
        ]
    }
    $.each($('ul.ingredients > li > h4'), function (index, ingredient) {
        recipeobj.ingredients[index].ingredient = $(ingredient).html();
        recipeobj.ingredients[index].optional = false;
    })
```

If I try to do `console.log(recipeobj.ingredients)` I just get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: ingredient is not defined`

No doubt this is simple, I just rarely need to use arrays in JavaScript so have little experience with them.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with arrays and objects. What is `optional` for?

Comment: You are mixing javascript and javascript object notation.  Then you have other syntax issues.

Comment: @eyegropram no problem with that, javascript object notation (JSON) is Javascript. The main problem is that he uses variables before they are defined. But yet, the final desired structure is not very clear. Frayt, could you post an example of what the final `recipeobj` should look like?

Comment: I wasn't alluding to a difference in languages.  He's mixing styles and is missing a core understanding of how to structure the code.

Comment: @blex The `optional` property is to indicate whether an ingredient is optional to the recipe. I realise that my current code sets every ingredient's `optional` property to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Open your console and run it**

```js
var recipeobj = {
  title: $('h3.title').html(),
  // ingredients is empty for now
  ingredients: []
};

$.each($('ul.ingredients > li > h4'), function(index, ingredient) {
  // Get the name
  var name = $(ingredient).html(),
      // Find out if it is 'optional'(using a class here)
      optional = $(ingredient).hasClass('optional');
  // Push a new ingredient into the array
  recipeobj.ingredients.push({ name: name, optional: optional });
});

console.log(recipeobj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="title">Pork and beans</h3>

<ul class="ingredients">
  <li>
    <h4>Pork</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>Beans</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4 class="optional">Salt*</h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This should output:

```
{
    "title": "Pork and beans",
    "ingredients": [
        { name : "Pork", optional : false },
        { name : "Beans", optional : false },
        { name : "Salt*", optional : true}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks blex, please see my comment on eyegropram's answer to get a better understanding of the structure

Comment: @Frayt Updated. Try it and open your console

Answer (score 0):

```
var rObj = {
        title: $('h3.title').val(),
        ingredients: [
                'source cream',
                'cheese',
                'chopped meat'
        ],
        optional: true
    };
```

accessing

```
var rItem = rObj.ingredients[1];
```

or you want

```
var rObj = {
        title: $('h3.title').val(),
        ingredients: {
                ingredient_list: ['one','two','three'],
                optional: true
        }
    };
```

accessing

```
var rItem = rObj.ingredients.ingredient_list[1];
```

The structure you are attempting to use looks like the structure should be like

```
var rObj = {
            title: $('h3.title').val(),
            things: [{
                ingredient: 'source cream',
                optional: true
            },
            {
                ingredient: 'cheese',
                optional: false
            }]
        };
```

accessing

```
var ingred = rObj.things[1].ingredient;
```

Comment: The third example is exactly what I'm trying to get: an array of ingredient objects. I imagine the working outcome to look like `ingredients: [{ ingredient: 'source cream', optional: false},{ingredient: 'cheese', optional: false}]

Comment: Yes indeed, that is more like what it appears you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
 var rObj = {
        title: $('h3.title').val(),
        ingredients : []
    };
```

you can add ingredients:

```
      $.each($('ul.ingredients > li > h4'), function (index, ingredient) {
     rObj.ingredients.push({ingredient: $(ingredient).html(), optional       :false})
 })
```